# Excel replace equation of ID by equation of values

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, equation

I have an excel column with multiple equation of ID like that for example :

56+78+(98&63)

---

32+87+21

---

12+(77&96&31)

And i have an other excel file with 2 columns (The ID and the correspond text) :

56 | ABC

---

78 | BCD

---

98 | GBF

---

63 | JIM

And i would like to replace in ID in equation by the corresponding text so it becomes :

56+78+(98&63) => ABC+BCD+(GBF&JIM)

I just know some easy formula, tried to combine some REPLACE, SEARCH, LOOKUP fucntion but didn't worked.

Thanks in advance for helping !

Answer (score 0):

For this it would be easy to have access to `LET()` and dynamic arrays through Microsoft Excel 365:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),Y,FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT("<t><s>",IF(ISNUMBER(--X),X,"</s><s>"&X&"</s><s>"),"</s></t>"),"&","&"),"//s[.!='']"),CONCAT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Y,C$1:D$4,2,0),Y)))
```

As you can see, no translations in your 2nd and 3rd samples since it couldn't find a proper translation in your lookup-table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked but i'm with Microsoft Office Standard 2019 and i don't have access to LET() function. Maybe there is a way to replace LET() function by adding some more functions

Comment: @Lucas You should tag the question with `excel-2019`.